# Servlet.init() for servlet example threw exception

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

i am getting exception while running this program in eclipse.
Servlet.init() for servlet example threw exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

### index.html

```
<a href="hello">Call hello</a>
```

### web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"           
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.lara</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-mvc1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-mvc1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

   </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

### example-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
    <prop key="hello">helloId</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="helloId" class="com.lara.HelloController"/>
```

### HelloController

```
package com.lara;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class HelloController implements Controller{
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello to all");
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("success.jsp");
    return mav;
    }
}
```

### exception

```
type Exception report
message Servlet.init() for servlet example threw exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet example threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]:     Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:770)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:737)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerAdapters(DispatcherServlet.java:557)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:411)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:398)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:52)
org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:100)
org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:69)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate     [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:770)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:737)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerAdapters(DispatcherServlet.java:557)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:411)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:398)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:52)
org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:100)
org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:69)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createConcurrentMapIfPossible(I)Ljava/util/Map;
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.InternalPathMethodNameResolver.<init>(InternalPathMethodNameResolver.java:46)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.<init>(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:125)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:291)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:770)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:737)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerAdapters(DispatcherServlet.java:557)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:411)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:398)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:52)
org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:100)
org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:69)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using spring-context 4.1.3.RELEASE with spring-webmvc 2.5.6. That can't possibly work. Use 4.1.3.RELEASE for both.