# What Jersey 2.x library version will solve this issue?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, servlets

This error is to do with library versions, but I can't pin it down.

I'm working through a REST example on Crunchify: [Link](https://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)

Link to a copy of the project: [Temp Converter Challenge](https://github.com/username917/Temerature-Converter-Challenge/)

I am using Java 11, version 1.8, with Tomcat 9 as the runtime environment. Dynamic web module version is 4.0.0.

I am getting the following error:
[image]

One of the recommended error fixes uses Jersey 2.x, whereas the project is originally built with Jersey 1.x, and the two are apparently incompatible, if mixed. This is the fundamental cause of the error, and I don't know what versions of Jersey 2.x to use, after trying a bunch without success.

I've updated the pom and web.xml files to reflect Jersey 2.x, which is also the recommended Jersey edition to use.

The pom file looks like this ,and the commented content is Jersey 1.x:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                                    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</groupId>
    <artifactId>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
              <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
              <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        
        
        
        
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency> -->
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Some changes from the original:

I said to target version 1.8, not 1.7, as even the guide suggests 1.8, but you can't do it without specifying it in the file. Also, I've added the following dependency due to an error in the pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

I've also changed the xml content, as the servlet also has to be compliant with a Jersey version. Commented out is the version for Jersey 1.x

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
 
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.crunchify.restjersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/crunchify/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Running the project on its own yields the following:
[image]

I have further tried a suggestion out of the comments on the project  for a 2020 version of Eclipse, to no avail.

I've reviewed a number of similar questions, including the comments under the example. This is just a selection of what I've looked up so far:

[How to fix 'javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init()' Error for Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630158/how-to-fix-javax-servlet-servletexception-servlet-init-error-for-tomcat)

[Jersey with Spring Error : Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364003/jersey-with-spring-error-servlet-init-for-servlet-jersey-rest-service-threw)

[Servlet.init() for servlet example threw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453087/servlet-init-for-servlet-example-threw-exception)

Maybe the example is too old, but everything points to library versions that are causing it to not work properly, and I can't figure out which versions I ultimately need.

UPDATE, Apr. 9 2022:

Stack Trace for project:

```
Apr. 09, 2022 2:01:00 P.M. com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Apr. 09, 2022 2:01:01 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Apr. 09, 2022 2:01:01 P.M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [Jersey Web Application]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:602)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Adding the proper UR:  http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample/crunchify/ctofservice/ - helps to get to the page, but then I get a JAXB bind error, that is resolved here: https://crunchify.com/java-11-and-javax-xml-bind-jaxbcontext/

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: @Ray sorry for delayed response, had issues getting the server to run. I've posted the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to fix the problem

Actually, when cloning your GitHub project, I only had to make sure that the two `<servlet-name>` entries in *web.xml* are exactly the same. Yours are different, because you changed one after copying the file from the tutorial, but not both.

```xml
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
```

I built your example with `mvn clean package`, then created a run configuration for a locally installed Tomcat 9.0.62, adding the WAR as a deployment,

[image: Tomcat deployment config]

started the server, and it worked immediately:

[image: Browser, opening application URL]

### Jersey and ASM versions

You are using super old software versions, e.g. Jersey 2.13 is so old that it is not even contained in the [Eclipse Jersey](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey) GitHub repository which started 2018 with a first release [2.28-RC1](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/tree/2.28-RC1-RELEASE). In order to find the archived legacy [GlassFish Jersey](https://github.com/javaee/jersey) repository, I had to look around first.

Anyway, Jersey 2.13, the version you selected for your project, internally uses ASM 5.0.2 according to the [POM](https://github.com/javaee/jersey/blob/ba7a00a3e3271219ded6faa7de7382d366637e32/pom.xml#L1467). I see ASM 3.3.1 in your own POM, which according to the [ASM release notes](https://asm.ow2.io/versions.html) does not even support Java 7 fully yet. Yet you are compiling to Java 8 byte code version according to your Maven Compiler settings. So whatever ASM does in your project, you want to use at least a version supporting Java 8. That would be at least ASM 5.0, so I recommend to stick with the version used by Jersey, 5.0.2.

But that does not fix your problem. The stack trace actually says there is a problem in `jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader`, i.e. in an ASM class packaged and relocated into Jersey itself. It is not using the old version you specified in your POM. I could not reproduce your problem here locally. I just wanted to mention that.

#### Optimise the POM

Later, I used `mvn dependency:analyze` in order to find out which dependencies you are actually using. ASM is unused in your servlet, like I said. So you can remove it. You only need Jersey, JSON and Jakarta WS-RS API, which is a transitive dependency of one of the Jersey libraries, but you should still reference it in your POM, if you access its classes. Relying on transitive dependencies is not the clean Maven way. I also upgraded the plugins you use and JSON dependency, then removed everything unused. The new POM looks like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20220320</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>2.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.35</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### GitHub pull request

https://github.com/username917/Temerature-Converter-Challenge/pull/2

Comment: **Update:** In an earlier version of this answer I falsely said that you do not need Jersey in your POM. But that was wrong, of course. I had simply deployed the wrong artifact when trying.

Comment: **Update 2:** I created a pull request for you, see the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @kriegax, thank you so much for the exhaustive answer. Granted, I did not fully appreciate the age of the versions involved, but what you've mentioned here connects the dots for me significantly better. Thank you for taking the time. I've confirmed that the example works now, as well.